# How to measure Electromotive induced force and current?

Tags: electric-circuits

I'm doing an experiment on Faraday's law.

I have a 100times looped wire connected with a galvanometer. and I will use a magnet to induce current by putting it in and out of the loop.

and, I'd like to put a bulb in the circuit, so when current is induced it flows through the bulb and we can visually look at it.

1. When I put a magnet in and out of the loop, does it induce Voltage or Current? or both? This is confusing me.
2. I'd like to measure the induced voltage or current in the circuit and figure out how much voltage or current the circuit would need to light a bulb. (A bulb is in Watt ; p=iv. So if I know either i or v, I could figure out how much either voltage or current this bulb needs to be lighten in the circuit, am I right?)
   So how could I do that here? could you please explain about it more detail on how to measure? and am I using a right equation?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The changing magnetic field induces an EMF in the loop. This EMF is given by [Faraday's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction):

$$ E = - \frac{d\Phi}{dt} $$

where $\Phi$ is the total magntic flux through the coil, which is dependent only on the strength of the magnet and the geometry. This EMF will in turn produce a current:

$$ I = \frac{E}{R} = - \frac{1}{R} \frac{d\Phi}{dt} $$

where $R$ is the total resistance of your coil and the light bulb. Since the wire probably has a negligible resistance compared to the light bulb the majority of the EMF will be dropped across the light bulb i.e. if you connect your voltmeter across the light bulb you will measure a voltage very close to $E$.

Unless you have a strong magnet you may struggle to generate enough current to light the bulb. I might be inclined to use something like a light emitting diode that requires less current. Or maybe use two LEDs of different colours wired in opposite directions. Then you should see one LED light as the magnet enters the coil and the other light as the magnet leaves the coil.